# "Type Not Usable in Add-on Platform" Error When Using CardService in Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-workspace

I am developing a Google Workspace add-on using Google Apps Script. I am encountering an issue while using CardService to create a UI that displays a list of GitHub repositories. The functionality I am trying to implement is to fetch and display a list of GitHub repositories as checkboxes, based on the user-provided GitHub username and token.

The problem occurs in the fetchRepositories function when constructing and returning a card using CardService. The error message is as follows:

```
The type of value returned from Apps Script is not usable in the add-on platform. Please call the 'build' function before returning this value.
```

This error only appears when the else block is executed, specifically when fetching the list of GitHub repositories using the username and token stored in user properties. Here's a snippet of the code in question:

```js
function fetchRepositories(e) {
  // ... some code omitted ...

  if (e) {
    // Processing user input
    var formInput = e.formInput;

  if (!formInput.githubUsername || !formInput.githubToken) {
      return CardService.newActionResponseBuilder()
        .setNotification(CardService.newNotification()
          .setType(CardService.NotificationType.ERROR)
          .setText("GitHub Username and Token are required."))
        .build();
    }
  } else {
    var userInfo = getUserCredentials();
    username = userInfo.username;
    token = userInfo.token;
  }

  var repos = getGitHubRepos(username, token);

  if (!repos) {
    return CardService.newActionResponseBuilder()
      .setNotification(CardService.newNotification()
        .setType(CardService.NotificationType.ERROR)
        .setText("Failed to fetch repositories."))
      .build();
  }

  var repoCheckboxes = CardService.newSelectionInput()
    .setType(CardService.SelectionInputType.CHECK_BOX)
    .setTitle("Select Repositories")
    .setFieldName("selectedRepos");

  repos.forEach(function(repo) {
    repoCheckboxes.addItem(repo.name, repo.name, false);
  });

  var card = CardService.newCardBuilder()
    .addSection(CardService.newCardSection().addWidget(repoCheckboxes))
    .addSection(
      CardService.newCardSection()
        .addWidget(CardService.newTextButton()
          .setText("Add Selected Commits to Calendar")
          .setOnClickAction(CardService.newAction()
            .setFunctionName("addSelectedCommitsToCalendar"))))
      .build()

  return CardService.newActionResponseBuilder()
    .setNavigation(CardService.newNavigation().pushCard(card))
    .build();
}
```

The getGitHubRepos function calls the GitHub API and returns a list of repositories. I am using the returned repos array to create a list of checkboxes.

I am seeking advice on what to check and modify to resolve this issue. Thank you.